# Difference between launch and launch_ros

Tags: ros2, roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Possibly a silly question, but here goes: What is the difference between ros2/launch and ros2/launch_ros? When should one be used over the other?

They both have similar names, and (superficially) similar jobs, so I'm a little unclear which one I should be more heavily leaning on when writing ROS 2 launch files.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/325167/difference-between-launch-and-launch_ros/) by [jhassold](https://answers.ros.org/users/40639/jhassold/) on ROS Answers with karma: 50 on 2019-06-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-06-10**:
I'm going to wait for a more authoritative answer, but: the former is a generic library that implements the domain concepts and infrastructure to "launch" (ie: start) multiple *processes* in a uniform way with support for coordination and monitoring of all those tasks, while the latter is a library/tool that builds on-top of the former and adds ROS-specific domain concepts which makes it usable to start, coordinate and monitor multiple *ROS nodes* (which also happen to be mappable onto processes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`launch` and `launch_testing` are ROS agnostic and is used in the core libraries to do testing (e.g. before you have things like rclpy or rclcpp), but `launch_ros` and `launch_testing_ros` just add ROS specific concepts to launching and testing, leveraging dependencies like rclpy.

For now, I'd recommend using `launch_ros` as your dependency for just writing launch files. For testing, I'd recommend `launch_testing_ros`, but we're thinking about having a "`ros2test`" or similarly named package that collects all the parts for you in a single package.

This is issue describes the layout of the code a bit:

https://github.com/ros2/launch/issues/208

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2019-06-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3